# Apacheがスタートしない

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

初めてXAMPPを使う者です。
XcodeとMySQLを繋ぎたくて、XAMPP(7.1.29-1)をmacにインストールしました。

テキストに沿ってApacheの設定をしているのですが、サーバーが起動（？）しません。

Server Eventsにはこのような部分が赤文字で書かれていました。

```
myMacBook-Air.local proftpd[79397]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'myMacBook-Air.local'
myMacBook-Air.local proftpd[79397]: error: no valid servers configured
myMacBook-Air.local proftpd[79397]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

これはどこを直せばいいのでしょうか？
他に必要な情報があれば教えてください！

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: > `テキストに沿って` とありますが、参考にしたものが技術書などなら内容や手順を引用し、WebサイトならURLを記載すると回答が得られやすくなります（回答者は、そのテキストがどのようなものであるのか分からないので）。

Comment: わかりました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/hosts`ファイルに以下のエントリを追加してみてください。

```
127.0.0.1   myMacBook-Air.local
```

参考: 英語版SOでの類似質問とその回答

[XAMPP , PROFTPD problems - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52587865/2322778)

Comment: 動きました！ありがとうございます！